# Problems passing functions in flex / actionscript 3

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, web-services

I'm new to flex and I am building a wrapper class for the WebService object to make my main code mxml cleaner. I am trying to pass a function to a class method to set as the result event handler for the soap call and it is not working as expected.

Here is the class:

```
package
{
    import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
    import mx.rpc.soap.WebService;

    public class WebServiceObject
    {
        private var wsdl:String = "http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/TestWs?wsdl";
        private var testWs:WebService;

        public function WebServiceObject()
        {
            try {
                testWs = new WebService(wsdl);
                testWs.loadWSDL();
            } catch(errObject:Error) {
                trace(errObject.toString());
            }
        }

        public function getSomething(resultHandler:Function):void
        {
            testWs.getSomething.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, resultHandler);
            testWs.getSomething.send();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import WebServiceObject;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        private function test():void
        {
            var test:WebServiceObject = new WebServiceObject();
            test.getSomething(handler);
        }

        public function handler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            trace(event.result);
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Button label="Test" click="test();"/>
</mx:Application>
```

The web service call is started and the call goes out but the result does not get passed back to the event listener. I tried using a class method as the handler and got the same result. All the pieces work if they are in the mxml code tag.

Is this doable? Am I missing something?

Thanks.

EDIT:

OK apparently (this didn't work):

```
testWs = new WebService(wsdl);
testWs.loadWSDL();
```

is not the same as (this did work, note where the wsdl URL is passed in):

```
testWs = new WebService();
testWs.loadWSDL(wsdl);
```

and I was quite sure that I tried it both ways... anyway problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

This should be working from the looks of things. Perhaps the WebServiceObject is being garbage collected before the event fires? Try storing it in a Class level variable. It does seem odd.

Comment: @Jim Ford when you figure something out, please post the solution. It may help the rest of us.

Comment: the solution was: testWs = new WebService(); testWs.loadWSDL(wsdl); instead of testWs = new WebService(wsdl); testWs.loadWSDL(); see my edit above with formatting.